# Autocomplete listener change Vue data

Tags: vue.js

I haves this code:

```
data() {
   return {
      markers: [],
   };
},

methods: {
   var partidaAutoComplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("partida"));
   partidaAutoComplete.addListener("place_changed", function() {
      var place = partidaAutoComplete.getPlace();
      var partidaLatLng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(
        place.geometry.location.lat(),
        place.geometry.location.lng()
      );
      var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({ position: partidaLatLng });
      this.markers.push(marker);
   });
}
```

When i'm trying push my marker into data variable markers the console show me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I understand it's an asynchronous method, but how could I retrieve the listener marker and assign it in my component

Comment: Apart from the fact that there should be a method declared in your `methods` property, I think the problem is that you are declaring your event handler like this: `function () {}` - this will create its own context(its own `this`), so you won't be able to access the component instance. Try using an arrow function: `prop.addEventListener(eventName, () => { /* console.log(this) - will refer to the vue instance */ })`

Comment: solved my problem, thank you very much!